# Unable to read the dynamic value from json file in jmeter

Tags: json, jmeter, performance-testing

I am reading the .json file from file upload in jmeter and in json file I have passed ${name} but somehow this dynamic value of name is getting read and the same thing if I am passing in reqest body of jmeter the correct value are getting read.

please help me out to read the dynamic value from external json file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) or something like this to fetch the value from the file on the file system you can read the file using normal [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler and [`file` protocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/jj710207(v=vs.85)):

[image]

More information: [How to Extract Data From Files With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/extracting-data-files-jmeter)

Comment: Thanks. Actually I have one post request from which I am getting ID in response and want to use that ID as a part of another PUT request but that request is too large hence reading the request from .json file (using file upload) but wanted to pass the id value in one of the field of .json file. Kindly help me out with this.